# Delete LVM and anything related to it

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

I want to delete /dev/sdb disk from the server. Before doing that I guess I should remove lvm and anything related to it. I don't care about /dev/sdb1 data.

I'm trying to follow this article https://www.golinuxhub.com/2014/03/how-to-remove-logical-and-physical.html

```
lvremove /dev/mapper/VolGroup01-LogVol00
```

but during the second command I get the following error

```
vgreduce VolGroup01 /dev/sdb1
Can't remove final physical volume "/dev/sdb1" from volume group "VolGroup01"
```

Also tried `vgchange -an VolGroup01`
and then  `vgreduce VolGroup01 /dev/sdb1` but still same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to "reduce" a volume group to nothing. Instead, to delete it, use `vgremove`.

```
vgremove VolGroup01
```

Now you can remove the LVM volume label from the physical volume with `pvremove`.

```
pvremove /dev/sdb1
```

And now you can remove or repurpose the disk.

Comment: @user Yes, that removes the logical volume.

Comment: okay thanks. Makes sense

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I had given myself a headache from aborting in the middle of `pvmove` operation and `vgremove` was getting a "busy" error. The solution was to use `pvremove --force --force` (yes, the `--force` flag twice).

In your situation:

```
pvremove /dev/sdb1 --force --force
```

Then, I could finally use:

```
vgremove VolGroup01
```

Of course, everything on `sdb1` was lost, but I was able to remove the LVM and start over.